# R calculate weighted averages for time series with missing values

Tags: r, apply, weighted-average

I have 3 time series with missing values (T1, T2 and T3). I merged them into a zoo object called x 
(you can download it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xk4qn9hthibqpu/x.rda?dl=0).

I want to calculate the weighted averages using 2 sets of weights (w1 and w2).
Here is what I do:

```
library(zoo)
load("x.rda")

w1 <- c(0.38,0.04,0.58)
w2 <- c(0.53,0,0.47)

average1 <- zoo(apply(x, 1, function(rw,w) weighted.mean(rw, weights=w, na.rm=TRUE), w1 ), order.by=index(x) )
average2 <- zoo(apply(x, 1, function(rw,w) weighted.mean(rw, weights=w, na.rm=TRUE), w2 ), order.by=index(x) )

plot(average1-average2)
```

But average1 and average2 are identical. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The dropbox link is not working anymore. Can you provide an example, so that your question remains understandable?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, the link is now working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?weighted.mean`.  The name of the argument is `w`, not `weights` :

```
avg1 <- avg2 <- x[, 1]
avg1[] <- apply(x, 1, weighted.mean, w = w1, na.rm = TRUE)
avg2[] <- apply(x, 1, weighted.mean, w = w2, na.rm = TRUE)
```